# Facebook like button lost count (Wordpress WP Socializer)

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I did an update of wordpress from version 3.6 to version 3.8. After the update, the facebook and all other social share counters were lost. I am using the WP Socializer plugin to show all of the buttons. I didn't change the URLs on the way, as I understand the counters are bound to the URL.

Now my question: Is there some way to restore the counters? Are the values saved somewhere? I couldn't find anything valuable by googling.

Thanks!

Comment: Like counts are bound to the specific URL by Facebook, yes – so they should definitively not be “lost”. But if anything changed on your end regarding the URLs (in general, or the canonical URL given for a piece of content, or redirects to another address), then you will have to set that back to the old ones to see your likes again.

Comment: Indeed, the URLs changed because of language functionality I added. Thanks for pointing it out again @CBroe .